# Importing classes with * in Java instead of listing them specifically

Tags: java, import

If you had a single class you needed to import, say java.util.Random, would naming it specifically in the import statement like
    import java.util.Random;
use less memory than
    import java.util.*;
And would this change if you were using multiple classes from java.util? How about if you were using all the classes in java.util?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imports are used only by the compiler. At runtime, the bytecode uses the fully qualified name of every class used. The bytecode is exactly the same whether you use * imports or not.

Answer (score 3):

It's highly unlikely that you'll use ALL the classes in the `java.util` package.  Or Swing.  Or any of the others that are rather large.

An IDE can easily add them individually, so the typing isn't an issue.

I prefer doing it that way because it makes my intent clearer.

You sound like you don't understand what `import` really does.  It has nothing to do with class loading or memory.  It has everything to do with saving you typing.  When you import `java.sql.Connection`, it means the compiler will allow you to refer to that class by its short name instead of the fully resolved name - that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol * is replaced by the respective classes used in your program at its compile time. If you have any decompiler you can check it that the generated source file from **.class** containing the import statements with their names.